# Confluence pocketquery macro fetching unwanted word along with result from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, macros, confluence

Hi I'm using a Confluence macro called 'PockketQuery'(PQ). I have connected to a server located at my client's base through PostgreSQL. I run PQ to fetch results from the db into my confluence page. However, it's fecthing an extra unwanted word "Hallo" along with every result. I m unable to figure out where this string maybe coming from and getting attached to my results like this. Please help me get rid of it.
For example I run a PQ on the db which is supposed to fetch me result "Jack London", so the result that I see is "hallo Jack London".
Note: I use VPN to connect to my client's server and Confluence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest version from the Marketplace 1.14.6? This issue shouldn't exist in the latest version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Felix but I just checked that my organization is currently using the version 1.14.4. Although version 1.14.6 is available for update but I want to be very sure that this problem is occurring because I'm on an older version, since getting updates of add-ons is an admin action and will require some discussions and approvals.
Also, is this a known issue? Have you encountered something of this sort with PQ?
Even if it is a bug with the older version, where's this odd word even coming from... :(

Answer (score 0):

I got an upgrade to version 1.14.6 of Confluence's PocketQuery macro. The issue that I had is resolved, the unwanted string in the result is there no more. The bad part is they don't mention it anywhere on the macro's bug fixes. There are no release notes attached to this fix.Thank you Felix for your help.